# Download DocumentSet as zip using csom

Tags: sharepoint-addin

How do I download a documentset as zipped file using SharePoint client object model.

Answer (score -2):

Please check the following links:

[Download Document Set as zip](http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/download-document-set-as-zip/)

[Create a SharePoint Custom Action to Zip and Download a Document Set](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnwpowell/archive/2012/01/21/create-a-sharepoint-custom-action-to-zip-and-download-a-document-set.aspx)

Comment: Please take more time to read the question before answering. The question clearly specified the use of the client object model yet the posts you linked have nothing to do with the client object model. In fact, one of the posts specifically states that the given solution will not work with the client object model.

Comment: I have down-voted this as being "not useful" for the reasons given above. Nothing personal - appreciate Sergey taking the effort to respond (nobody else did so far), it just isn't that useful to the OP.

Comment: According to [SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model Hierarchy and Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537855(v=office.14).aspx): `Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 has three object models for working on the client-side. These are the managed .NET object model, the managed Silverlight object model, and the unmanaged ECMAScript (JavaScript, JScript) object model.` First link has working solution with source code, second provides custom action using javascript. Where i am wrong?

Comment: I didn't find client side API for doing this. One of the consultant from MS also said that client side API is not available for it :(